# Why isn't my hover able to click a dynamically created ajax box?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to have a program that add's a Google plus user to my circles using selenium.   I have been able to locate the add to circles button and hover it so it displays a drop down.   However, the dynamic div container which contains my circles isn't in the dom tree until you hover.   For some reason selenium cannot see the xpath's for the items in the dynamic box created after the hover.   Does anybody have any idea why this doesn't work?  I've tried many different search, xpath methods so it seems the div doesn't exist within the current selenium browser object.

the code below actually hovers the box, but I can do nothing with it from there.

```
hoverBox = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contentPane"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/span')
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(hoverBox)
hover.perform()
```

Comment: if I look for the xpath, class name or id name it fails to find it.  It does manage to hover the add to your circle button but beyond that your actual circles cannot be found via xpath, css, id etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

import the above.

```
public static String executeScript(WebDriver driver, String scriptToExecute)
{
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  Object obj = executor.executeScript(scriptToExecute);
  if(obj != null)
  {
    return obj.toString();
  }
  else
  {
    return "";
  }
}
```

you can pass any script similar to "$('.context_menu').show()"

Comment: Where does `WebUtilities` come from